# Not Able to see All Product In Shopping cart in magento Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, magento-1.9.2.1

Kindly check attached Snap-shot , which in under Shopping cart Its showing 98 Items but, I m not able to see all, it showing only 15 to 20 , and there is no Drop-down or pagination, pl help to solve this issue .
[image]

Comment: did you checked under `shopping cart` menu present in middle of left menu.....

Comment: Yes, I got it, But, Can u please help me to Get product Image. in grid, i have check this File but. im not able to find code.  app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

Comment: please post different question for that.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed under `Customer view` section, you didt find full list, so you can check under **shopping cart menu present in middle of left menu.....** you will find all the items....